# Performing lookup on list of ranges

Tags: algorithm

I have a list of ranges that I want to make queries against. The ranges are in order and do not overlap.

Ex:

1-10,
11-17,
18-20,
21-30,
etc...

Currently I use a modified binary search. But I now have a new list...with the new list besides being non-overlapping ranges, the ranges can now be bitmasked.

Ex:

0-255,
256-287,
288-303,
etc...

There are a couple thousand ranges, ending at about 500,000

I'll be implementing this in c, but the language doesn't really matter. I'm just looking for some ideas on how to leverage this new property. Has anyone ever encountered this/read about it? If anybody has any thoughts they would be most welcome. :)

Comment: What does it mean for a range to be "bitmasked"?

Comment: Perhaps a [segment tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) is what you're looking for?

Comment: this is from my school, but are you by any chance using these? https://www.student.cs.uwaterloo.ca/~cs240/w11/slides-tb/slides17.pdf

Comment: what do you mean by do queries against? Do you need only to tell if there is a segment covering a given value? Or should you also say which range is that? 
@BartKiers in both cases I don't think a segment tree will help for this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about holding a bit-vector of size 500000? That would take about 61kb.

Then you can query whether a number is in a range in O(1) by performing AND. You can also query multiple values simultaneously. Also, setting up the range bit vector will be very fast as you don't require sorting.